# Call to member function on a non-object with instance variable

Tags: php, oop, object, count, instance

I have the below code which, when run, returns this error:

PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function count() on a non-object in /classes/User.php on line 36

```
public function find($user = null) {
    if($user) {
        $field = (is_numeric($user)) ? 'id' : 'email';
        $data = $this->_db->get('*', 'users', array($field, '=', $user));
        if($data->count()) { // This is line 36, the $_db variable is an instance of the DB class
            $this->_data = $data->first();
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

What am I missing that is making $data not refer to an object?

Comment: The error message does not pertain the `$_db` variable. It's about `$data`. Look up the documentation on your `->_db->get()` method to find out if it ought to return an object or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty simple, though the solution may not be: `$this->_db->get` is not returning an object. Depending on what `_db` is - is it an abstraction layer? Some crazy homebrew thing? Just looking at the syntax:

```
$this->_db->get('*', 'users', array($field, '=', $user));
```

I get a little weirded out - assuming that it's describing how keys are separated from search values, I've never seen a DB layer like that (and how often does SQL change what `=` does, anyway?) I'm willing to bet your database layer needs some attention, but that might be editorializing a bit. ;)

Chances are whatever it is, it's returning an error - it's (unfortunately) fairly commonplace for an object library to return FALSE instead of an object with an error code. It could even be returning an error *string.* Echo that bad boy and see what you get, and then fix whatever's causing it.

Comment: The DB class is abstracted. The parameters of get() basically mean SELECT * FROM users WHERE $field = $user which should return a PDO object.

Comment: Yes, that's what I said. So you're wrapping PDO? Why?